# GET request not getting data in codepen but working on browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, codepen

[This](https://codepen.io/iamanoopc/pen/JEjYKR?editors=0011) is my Codepen for a simple weather app I did long ago. However, it is not working now. When I paste the `api` into browser tab, I'm getting data, but in the Codepen it is not working.

```
var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
q=Lam%20Tin,HK&appid=23a5271ef6a94716ac17ec27e9f4bcd8";
$.getJSON(api, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: check the `console.log`(f12 mode) of codepen .some service blocked by default

Comment: I found this error..`The page at 'https://codepen.io/iamanoopc/pen/JEjYKR?editors=0011' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lam%20Tin,HK&appid=23a5271ef6a94716ac17ec27e9f4bcd8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: error as been showed very clearly .`HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest `.your http call is insecure .For the security reason .they will blocked your request `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS` . Better try with your  localhost

Comment: I understand, but what I need is the Codepen project to be working online, I cannot achieve that using localhost. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Error**

```
The page at 'https://codepen.io/iamanoopc/pen/JEjYKR?editors=0011' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lam%20Tin,‌​HK&appid=23a5271ef6a‌​94716ac17ec27e9f4bcd‌​8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

**Explanation**

[image]

error as been showed very clearly .*`HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest`* .Is secure domain server `https` .your http call is insecure .For the security reason .They will blocked your request *`This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS`*

**Alternate**

Try with insecure `http` domain server snippet like jsbin

[image]

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/lewepebawa/edit?html,output) with [`Jsbin`](http://jsbin.com/)